# Weblogic 10.3.3 :: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()

Tags: spring-data-jpa, weblogic-10.x, hibernate-jpa

I get the error

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInfo(LogHelper.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:520)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:50)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
```

I'm using weblogic 10.3.3 and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar.
I even tried setting this jar in the server's startup classpath so it doesn't conflict with the server's JPA but the error still exists.

Not sure how to resolve this error . Any suggestions?